# Nginx redirect image to the post

Tags: image, redirect, nginx, jpeg

It is possible to redirect with nginx like :
http://mydomain.com/users/image/9999-some-word-some-word-some-word.f3fd78ba6853a5be0c9caf5517429b15.jpg

to http://mydomain.com/node/9999

Answer (score 0):

well I guess you can try something like

```
location /users/image/([0-9]+) {
    try_files /node/$1.jpg =404;
}
```

or
Not sure about the rewrite exactly but it should be close to something like this

```
location /users/image/ {
    rewrite /users/image/([0-9]+).* /users/image/$1.jpg;
}
```